# How to get the "document" DOM node in karma-runner

Tags: karma-runner

I am trying to write a test for an existing web app in Karma with Jasmine.

In my index.html file, I have a  tag that contains a function that makes a call along the lines of:

```
document.getElementById("myButton")
```

This works fine when using the web app in a browser, but when running the test in Karma "document" appears to be referring to the context.html document, not my app's index.html document (so getElementById returns null, as it is looking in the wrong place).

**How am I supposed to get references to the HTML elements in JS that is being tested by Karma?**

I would expect it to pick up the right document by default, as the Javascript is in that HTML file.

Here is the simplest example that demonstrates my problem (which doesn't even need a test included to demonstrate the failure!):

**karma.conf.js:**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/main/webapp/public/index.html',
    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="myButton" disabled>My Button</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = false;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running `karma start` then produces the following output:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket 43zhn5jHmSmDU4QzUqQ6 with id 83536471
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 7) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null
  at C:/***/src/main/webapp/public/index.html:7
```

I'm very new to Karma, so I presume I'm missing something, but this is preventing me from even getting started with it.